# Resize /dev/root on CentOS 7.4

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos

I'd like to give /dev/root more space on my CentOS 7.4 system.

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G   18G  302M  99% /
devtmpfs        7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G   28K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.8G  826M  7.0G  11% /run
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       1.8T  2.7G  1.7T   1% /home
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

As you can see I have more than enough space mounted to /home.

```
# /sbin/fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf2e91416

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        4096    40962047    20478976   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        40962048  3905974271  1932506112   83  Linux
/dev/sda3      3905974272  3907020799      523264   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

How can I add 500 GB to /dev/root ?

Is this possible without going into rescue mode?

If not which commands do I need to do it in a Debian based rescue environment?

Edit: Ended up reinstalling with better partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any easy way to do this. I don't know how you finished up with `/` in your boot partition: normally this is mounted as `/boot/efi` (or it is on Ubuntu at least).

What I would do is:-

- Back up the whole disc `/dev/sda` (you'll need to do this anyway), then re-install from scratch, hoping to get the partition structure correct this time.
- Then from a Live Boot disc mount `/dev/sda2` (which is where `/` should be), maybe at `/mnt/newsys`, as well as the back-up of `/dev/sda1` (`/dev/sdb1`, perhaps?), maybe at `/mnt/oldsys`.
- Now run `cp -ua /mnt/oldsys/ /mnt/newsys/`.
- Next mount the back-up of `/dev/sda2`, perhaps at `/mnt/oldhome`.
- Lastly run `cp -ua /mnt/oldhome/ /mnt/newsys/home/`.

There may be ways to avoid regenerating, but you will probably spend more time trying to avoid it than you would doing it.